# how to resolve nguniversal-express-engine install issue in angular12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal, angular12

I am trying to install @nguniversal/express-engine in my angular12 application but I am getting error. I do not know why i am getting this error. If any one knows please help to resolve this issue.

```
Npm : = 7.5.4
Angular CLI: 12.2.5
Node: 14.17.6
```

Error:

```
> D:\Project\rkp>ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject projectname

> npm version 7.5.4 detected. When using npm 7 with the Angular CLI, npm
> version 7.5.6 or higher is recommended. i Using package manager: npm √
> Found compatible package version: @nguniversal/express-engine@12.1.0.
> √ Package information loaded.
> 
> The package @nguniversal/express-engine@12.1.0 will be installed and
> executed. 
  Would you like to proceed? Yes 
  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm
> ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'node' as it is null.
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-25T13_19_38_918Z-debug.log
> × Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Have u resolved the above issue?

Comment: I've got similar issue with Angular 13.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any answers?